# PHP - How to pass the content of a jquery variable into a sql query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I'd like to use the variable bradio in the "Having" clause of my query but i don't know how to get the content of the jquery variable and passe it into my sql query. This is a fragment of my php file. Can you tell me how can I do this?

Thanks

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","form-test","pass");
$db = mysql_select_db("form-test",$conn);

?> 
  <script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function()
    {

    jQuery('#event_form_field-<?php echo $event_id; ?>').click(function() 
    {
    var bradio= jQuery("input[type=radio]:checked").val()
            alert(bradio); });});
           </script>
 <?php  

$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(wp_events_answer.answer) as rep, wp_events_answer.attendee_id  as idq, wp_events_question.quota as quota2, wp_events_attendee.event_id as ev, wp_events_answer.answer as answ, wp_events_question.id as qst3
    FROM wp_events_answer, wp_events_attendee, wp_events_question
            WHERE wp_events_answer.question_id = wp_events_question.id AND wp_events_answer.attendee_id = wp_events_attendee.id
    HAVING answer = 
    GROUP BY answ;";

 $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {

}

?>
```

Comment: your mixing server and client side ... that wont work.
try to submit your client (JS) data to the server via a form or Ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix both PHP and javascript code in one page using the method above. The problem is because PHP is executed on the server, well before any javascript can be run on the client. Therefore, the two cannot speak to each other.

The solution here is to make an AJAX request to a PHP script on your server and pass the value of the radio control to it. This would then return the required data and you can then use javascript to display this on your page.

For example:

```
$.post(
    'myScript.php', 
    'bradio=' + jQuery("input[type=radio]:checked").val(),
    function(data) {
        // process your result here
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Write the query in another php file and pass the variable using an GET or POST or maybe ajax call

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot pass a js variable to php in this way. The php code is executed before the page has sent to the browser while the js code is executed after: you need instead an ajax call with the `bradio`value passed along the request (get or post)

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to send an POST Request and reload the page or you need to pass the variable via AJAX to the current page and change the output on the fly. Via jquery it's pretty simple to send an AJAX request via http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a request from javascript (`$.get` or `$.post`) and pass value of this radio button as a parameter. Then, on PHP side you will be able to get it from `$_GET` or `$_POST` array.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give me a little example?

Comment: There are examples in this topic.

Comment: thanks. I did HAVING answer = '" . $_GET ["bradio"]. "' but it does not works.

Comment: but do you send it from Javascript?